# How to call skype api in php

Tags: php, html, skype

I have some phone numbers diplayed from database. When i click on that number i have to call that number using skype.I am using a php code.

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Call the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service</a>
```

It works only if the system have skype installation.
If computer does not have skype i need a skype installation procedure.  Anyone help me.

Comment: Well ofcourse it only works if system has skype installed. How else are you gonna call someone 0.o

Comment: other case i need askype insatallation procedure on clicking the above link

Comment: `<p>Note: You will need to have Skype installed in order for the Skype buttons to work.</p>`

Comment: This has nothing whatever to do with PHP: anything you can do with this will be on the browser, so must be client-side code. What you're actually looking for is javascript code to detect whether skype is installed. I think the question I've linked as a dup basically asks the same question, and the answers should be helpful.

Comment: How can i implement using javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have answered your own question.

> It works only if the system have skype installation

### That is how it works.

The Skype API need to be there inorder to make calls right ?

If they don't have Skype, you can tell them to get it from the website like this

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Call the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service</a>, If you don't have Skype installed. Download it from <a href='http://www.skype.com'>here</a>
```

Comment: But i need automatic skype installation from skype......

Answer (score 1):

You could create a SIP phone, there is an open source one call sipML5, really easy to set up:

http://sipml5.org/

Then you can go to skype and set up a SIP account. From there you can then call other phones from your browser without having the need to install skype.